# Merge files by the last subfolder's name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge all files by the last subfolder's name.

Example:
say I have two files from each subfolder named: `45554` and `32456`.
Therefore their paths are like:

There are more files this is just an example

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INB\INB.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INB\INB.shp
```

so I need to merge all INB files to one and all INS files to one.

Here is my code: The problem is that it does a merge in all files and not in the groups I mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE")
files = []
for fil in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
    files.append(pd.read_table(fil).assign(col = get_folder(fil))) #needs group by somehow
gdf = pd.concat(files, sort = True)   #concatenate files
gdf.to_csv(folder / 'compiled')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 2 lists. One for "INB" and one for "INS":

```
INB = [], INS = []

for fil in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
    df = pd.read_table(fil).assign(col = get_folder(fil))
    if fil.endswith('INS.shp'):
        INS.append(df)
    else:
        INB.append(df)

INB_df = pd.concat(INB).to_csv('INB.csv')
INS_df = pd.concat(INS).to_csv('INS.csv')
```

For multiple categories, use a dictionary. For example:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for fil in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
    df = pd.read_table(fil).assign(col = get_folder(fil))
    d[os.path.basename(fil)].append(df)

for cat, lst in d.items():
    pd.concat(lst).to_csv(cat)
```